# Grant Resource Group owner to Personal and Business Account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group, azure-security

How do I grant my personal **and** business accounts, that have the same email addresses, resource owner of a resource group?

In my personal account, I created a resource group.  I went to `Resource Gruops -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add User` and added my email address but when I sign-in to the Azure portal w/ my business account I can't switch to that directory.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried explicitly adding that business account as a guest user in AAD? You might be able to then give the role via powershell at least if the portal doesn't work.

Comment: Hi  @juunas - When I try to add my business account directly to Azure AD I get: `'mydomain.com' is not a verified domain name in this directory` on the username field

Comment: When I try adding a `guest user` I get `User name already exists in this directory` @juunas